# Win 7 "tough" Network Questions

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares

I recently started looking more detailed into the Win 7 Network settings. Some things got more and more unclear the more I thought about it. Here are some of the questions:

### 1. Is it true, that you can only configure Settings for Network Profiles in Win 7 but not the settings for one specific Network?

What I mean here is, if you create a new network, Windows asks you to chose one of the profiles:
[image: 3 Profiles]
But afterwards if you want to change something regarding the settings for this network, and you click on the yellow marked:
[image: advanced network settings]

Then you get directed to the page for settings the network profiles. So if I change that, then I change it for my private network and my "Workspacenetwork".

### 2. Is it true, that the setting for "password protected sharing" (excuse my bad translation, maybe the German texted picture does help) has only meaning if the setting for "share file and printer" is turned on?

[image]

[image]

So for example if I allow other users to access my PC without Username and Password, but put the setting for "file sharing and printers" to no, then no one can access any files?

### 3. The Settings menu for media and the public folders ask separately if I want to share them. Are those settings superior to "password protected sharing" and "file sharing and printers"? And what is the order of superiority?

For example if I deactivate "file sharing and printers" but in the media sharing have the setting to share media, then everyone at work can see my pictures?

Or if I have public folder sharing on yes but "file sharing and printers" set to no, Can then somebody see the public folder or no?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi @user54512, this should probably be three separate questions.

Comment: Hi dsolimano, if someone is experienced the answers are probably very short and somewhat dependent on each other, so thinkt its best to have it all together..

Comment: Hm O.K. maybe i should split it in 3...